# Copying music files of iphone library in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, avassetwriter, mpmediapickercontroller

I want to copy the music files of iphone ipod library using MPMediaPicker. Actually using MPMediaPicker I am able to get the path of ipod music library but when I convert music file at url in NSData, the result is null. I doubt that is it possible to get the music file from ipod library. I am not sure as there is no exception or warning while I am trying to convert url item in NSData using [NSData datawithContentOfUrl:ipod-library-path].

If someone has any idea about this or any alternative to copy music files.

Comment: have you done with music library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting `Asset` `URL`of music files.So it need to be `converted` into `NSData` to `write` into `iphone` `library`.

Refer [Get video NSData from ALAsset url iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801656/1106035) link.

Now `write` `data` into `iphone` `library`.

Comment: Actually I made a quick response.Have you ever tried this code on music library.That worked perfectly for UIImagePicker but when using this ipod music library I got an error mentioning Error: Global denied access.I was getting the selected song URL as oneipod-library://item/item.wav?id=2720595644450418781 but converting this url in NSData gave  Error: Global denied access.That was my question that do we have access to music library?