# mach_vm_map(size=) failed (error code=3)

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am trying to save video from album to my document directory. It's working fine for videos less than 1 minute. But when I am trying to save videos more than 1 minute, my app is getting crashed. This is happening only in iPhone, in iPad it's working working for larger videos as well.

This is my code :

```
    else if([mediaType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
    {
        ALAssetsLibrary *librarys = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [librarys enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
         {
             [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];

             if ([group numberOfAssets] > 0)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < [group numberOfAssets]; j++)
                 {
                     [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:j]
                                             options:0
                                          usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
                      {
                          if (alAsset)
                          {
                              ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
                              NSURL *url = [representation url];

                              if ([[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] isEqual:url])
                              {
                                  Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc((unsigned)[representation size]);
                                  //NSUInteger buffered = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:representation.size error:nil];
                                  //Byte *buffer = ((Byte*)representation.size);
                                  //NSUInteger chunkSize = 100 * 1024;
                                 // uint8_t *buffer = malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(uint64_t));

                                  NSUInteger buffered = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)representation.size error:nil];
                                  NSData *videoCameraData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
                                  NSString *savedImagePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:str_Header];
                                  NSError *error;
                                  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:savedImagePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

My app is getting crashed at :

```
NSUInteger buffered = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)representation.size error:nil];
```

Error :

```
 malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=310386688) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: from your post I would say you request too much memory...

Comment: @Volker Is there any workout to save these videos without consuming so much memory?

Comment: splitting up the memory usage... or using a swap file... a ring buffer... anything that does reduce the allocation size of memory.

Comment: hi @volker...this answer of riven solved my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791049/get-video-nsdata-from-alasset-url-ios

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this bug while using Core Audio. I was able to fix it by setting compiler optimization to "-O0 None."