# App getting crashed (SIGABRT) while accessing main run loop?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, class

```
AppXYZ(2111,0xb04a3000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1207959552) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

How to get symbolicated information from the above debugger logs?

Like I need to know the class of the address (`0xb04a3000`), the exact location of the bug in the code and so on.

Comment: Here you will find some valuable responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648642/how-to-use-addr2line-command-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gdb, I would just do as it says, i.e. put a breakpoint in the function mentioned:

```
$ gdb AppXYZ
[... gdb starts ...]
gdb$ break malloc_error_break
gdb$ run
```

The reproduce the thing that caused the crash. Informally, it seems to be because it's trying to allocate more than 1 GB of memory in a single `malloc()` call, that's rather daring in some environments.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I would say that you ran out of memory.

```
Malloc was not able to allocate the requested memory
```

This is because you must have requested for large chunk of memory to be allocated with malloc.

I suggest you to decrease  the amount of memory to be allocated and try.

Refer [Malloc Error Code = 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970417/mach-vm-map-failed-error-code-3) and [Malloc Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504819/mach-vm-mapsize-failed-error-code-3) for more details