# How to access NSData/NSURL of slow motion videos using PhotoKit

Tags: ios, photokit, phasset

Working with new Photo framework, I can access the `NSData` of PHAssets using `requestImageDataForAsset`. I can also access the file URL using the `PHImageFileURLKey` of the returned `info NSDictionary`.

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

                //imageData contains the correct data for images and videos
                NSLog(@"info - %@", info);
                NSURL* fileURL = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
}];
```

This works fine for images and normal videos.

However, when the asset is a PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate (slow motion video), the returned data corresponds to a JPG file containing the first frame of the video (both the NSData, the dataUTI and the info dictionary point to the same jpg file). As example, this is the URL and the dataUTI returned for a slow motion video:

> PHImageFileURLKey =
>   "file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0642.JPG";
>   PHImageFileUTIKey = "public.jpeg";

Why is this happening? 
How can i access the NSData/NSURL of the slow motion video instead of this JPG preview?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After going nuts and testing every single option I found the problem.

The responsable of returning JPG images for slow motion videos is the default `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent` value for the `PHImageRequestOptions.version` property.

Simply assign the version to PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted or PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal will return the original slow motion video.

```
PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];

imageRequestOptions.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted;
// or 
imageRequestOptions.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
```

I consider this as an unexpected behaviour, since i am not expecting that the "current" version of a slow motion video is a still image (maybe a video with the slow motion effect applied, but not a photo).

Hope this is usefull to someone.

Comment: Do you know how to get NSData of slow motion video? I have tried requestAVAssetForVideo method but it returns AVComposition instead of AVAsset or AVURLAsset. My problem is how to get NSData from AVComposition.

Comment: You can cast asset to `videoAsset as? AVURLAsset` and get data in the following way `try? Data(contentsOf: videoAsset.url)`

Comment: @guiller ..,  Bro, thank you, it helped

Answer (score 13):

It is important to note that Slow motion videos are of type AVComposition not AVURLAsset. An AVComposition object combines media data from multiple sources together.

### **Exporting a slow motion video**

To achieve this, I basically went through a three-step process:

1. Create an output URL for the video
2. Configure an export session
3. Export the video and grab the URL!

---

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            if(([asset isKindOfClass:[AVComposition class]] && ((AVComposition *)asset).tracks.count == 2)){
                //slow motion videos. See Here: https://overflow.buffer.com/2016/02/29/slow-motion-video-ios/

                //Output URL of the slow motion file.
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;
                NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeSlowMoVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

                //Begin slow mo video export
                AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
                exporter.outputURL = url;
                exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
                exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

                [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                            NSURL *URL = exporter.outputURL;
                            self.filePath=URL.absoluteString;



                            // NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
                            //
                            //// Upload
                            //[self uploadSelectedVideo:video data:videoData];
                        }
                    });
                }];


            } 
        }];
```

Please see this wonderful [blog](https://overflow.buffer.com/2016/02/29/slow-motion-video-ios/) for slow motion videos in iOS.

Comment: Yes this was great. Really appreciate it! Saved me so much frustration.

Comment: This is for the case when you pick from photos library. What if I record a slow mo video and then want to upload it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514282/ios-avplayer-cant-play-240-fps-video

Answer (score 7):

Following code snippet for Swift 3/4

```
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, 
                                         options: nil, 
                                         resultHandler: { (asset, _, _) in

            // AVAsset has two sub classes: AVComposition and AVAssetURL
            // AVComposition for slow mo vid
            // AVAssetURL for normal videos

            // For slow motion video checking for AVCompostion
            // Creating an exporter to write the video into local file path and using the same to play/upload

            if asset!.isKind(of: AVComposition.self){

                let avCompositionAsset = asset as! AVComposition

                if avCompositionAsset.tracks.count > 1{

                    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avCompositionAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
                    exporter!.outputURL = self.fetchOutputURL()
                    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
                    exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

                    exporter!.exportAsynchronously {
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                          // Use this url for uploading or playing a video
                           let url = exporter!.outputURL
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{

                // Normal video, are stored as AVAssetURL

                let url = (asset as! AVURLAsset).url
            }
        })

// Fetch local path

 func fetchOutputURL() -> URL{
     let documentDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory() as NSString
     let path = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.mp4")
     return URL(fileURLWithPath:path)
 }
```

Comment: Could use following codes to generate output url: `let exportPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("\(fileName).mov")` `let exportUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: exportPath)`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Play Slow-Motion video from PHAsset**

```
private func handleAssetVideo(asset: PHAsset) {
    PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil) { avAsset, audioMix, info in
        guard let avAsset = avAsset else {
            return
        }
        if let avUrlAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
            //usual video
            let videoUrl = avUrlAsset.url
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //use videoUrl
            }
        } else if let avComposition = avAsset as? AVComposition {
            //slow-mo video
            guard avComposition.tracks.count > 1 else {
                return
            }

            guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
                return
            }
            
            let exportPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("temp.mp4")
            exportSession.outputURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: exportPath)
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
            
            exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
                guard let slowMotionUrl = exportSession.outputURL else {
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    //use slowMotionUrl
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("asset is not video")
        }
    }
}
```

[Optimizing for Slow Motion Video in iOS](https://buffer.com/resources/slow-motion-video-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

//video slo-mo

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options=[[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc]init];
options.version=PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
```

Request AVAsset from PHImageManager

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:videoAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info)
 {         
     if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]])
     {
         // use URL to get file content

         NSURL *URL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
         NSData *videoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
         NSNumber *fileSizeValue = nil;
         [URL getResourceValue:&fileSizeValue forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
      }
}
```

Comment: This won't give URL for slow motion video because slow motion video is combination 2 or more files.

Comment: We need to export the slow motion video. Moreover, The above method would give URL for objects of type AVURLAsset, but slow motion videos are of type AVComposition.