# How to convert an AVMutableVideoComposition to an AVAsset

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm doing some video editing and I need to put AVMutableVideoComposition I'm manipulation back into a player item. To go into a player item it needs to be an AVAsset. How to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/%20).

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Exporting AVComposition and getting local url to play and upload the video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46559459/2276920)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an `AVMutableComposition` as an `AVPlayerItem`'s asset since `AVMutableComposition` is a subclass of `AVAsset`.

An `AVMutableVideoComposition` is not a subclass of `AVAsset`, but rather a way to display the video that you've inserted into `AVAssetTracks` in an `AVMutableComposition`.

(If all of your videos are positioned the way you'd like without an `AVMutableVideoComposition`, then you may not need to set the player item's `videoComposition` property)

ObjC:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = ...
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = ...
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
item.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

Swift:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition(...
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(...
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
item.videoComposition = videoComposition
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this- exportPath can be any temporary path for keeping the video.

```
    func ConvertAvcompositionToAvasset(avComp: AVComposition, completion:@escaping (_ avasset: AVAsset) -> Void){
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avComp, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        let randNum:Int = Int(arc4random())
        //Generating Export Path
        let exportPath: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("\(randNum)"+"video.mov") as NSString
        let exportUrl: NSURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: exportPath as String) as NSURL
        //SettingUp Export Path as URL
        exporter?.outputURL = exportUrl as URL
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                if exporter?.status == .completed {
                    let URL: URL? = exporter?.outputURL
                    let Avasset:AVAsset = AVAsset(url: URL!)
                    completion(Avasset)
                }
                else if exporter?.status == .failed{
                    print("Failed")

                }
            })
        }) }
```