# Playing slow motion videos from camera make it loses slow motion effect

Tags: ios, video, phasset, photosframework, slowmotion

So, I have a custom picker controller in which I can select videos and play them. Beforehand, I was struggling to play slow motion videos (only no-slow-motion videos were playing) but after searching I found the solution here.

[How to access NSData/NSURL of slow motion videos using PhotoKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152396/how-to-access-nsdata-nsurl-of-slow-motion-videos-using-photokit)

Now, slow motion videos are playing but in a normal way instead of in a slow-motion way. This questions relates to the problem.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/903937#903937

I've seen a lot of comments saying they solved the problem by using Photos framework, but I have no idea how to achieve this and they didn't explain either. It might be something to do PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate. So, how would be possible to play slow motion videos? Do I need to change the fps somehow?