# Upload big video from PhotoLibrary to server

Tags: ios, video, upload, photolibrary

I have a problem with uploading big video asset to a server from PhotoLibrary.

I get my asset data as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545982/getting-video-from-alasset?answertab=active#tab-top), export the video to local document, and then upload.

But when I upload a big video (2 minutes and about 300Mb or more in size), this method causes a crash and I got no reason nor any any information.

I use `webDAV` to upload files just like this:

```
    // Set up credentials
    NSURLCredential *userCredentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                                  password:password
                                  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSURLProtectionSpace *space = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:host
                                                                        port:80
                                                                    protocol:@"http"
                                                                       realm:@" webDAV"
                                                        authenticationMethod:nil];
    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:userCredentials forProtectionSpace:space];
    [space release];

    // Create the request
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:[self mimetypeForFile:self.filepath] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSNumber *contentLength = (NSNumber *) [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                             attributesOfItemAtPath:self.filepath error:NULL]
                                            objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    [request setValue:[contentLength description] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    if (self.useStreaming)
    {
        if (self.currentFileStream!=nil)
        {
            [self.currentFileStream close], self.currentFileStream = nil;
        }
        self.currentFileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:self.filepath];

        if (currentFileStream!=nil)
        {
            [request setHTTPBodyStream:currentFileStream];
        }
        else
        {
            [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath]];
    }



    NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (self.currentConnection!=nil)
    {
        self.currentConnection = nil;
    }
    self.currentConnection = conn;
    [conn release];
    [self.currentConnection start];
```

When the code reache this line:

`self.currentFileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:self.filepath];
            [request setHTTPBodyStream:currentFileStream];`

OR:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath]];
```

It crashed.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

========================

**Edit: It crash at `setHTTPBody:` OR  `setHTTPBodyStream:`**
 So I think it's about memory leak or something.

================

**EDIT2:** Now I decide to compress video, I get video data by current method is too large(more than 300mb)， But I find use `UIImagePickerController` select the same video, it just 30mb； So compress is help; **I'll try `UIVideoEditorController`, and will post my result soon;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completed. the solution is try to compress big video to small file;**

1.just like before, export video asset to tmp directory;

2.use [UIVideoEditorController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009027) to compress the video file;

3.just upload compressed file like the code I post.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

check following post , where i am uploading image on server, instead of image you can post your video   [Uploading Image via POST in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c/15477035#15477035)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read it but find no solution; I mean I can upload video(small size)/image asset from PhotoLibrary to server successfully via webDAV like I described;  But when comes to big size video asset, it crash.  Is There any way can upload big size video asset from PhotoLibrary?

Comment: either you can create zip file of that asset to comprase size. then you can upload it. or you can divide your data into small packets and do upload.

Comment: I completed it, compress video asset by UIVideoEditorController, and then upload. I tried to divide data into small packets, but the server does not support join these small file into one; Thank you all the same， best wishes