# Whatsapp not picking the video from the assetURL in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, video, uiactivityviewcontroller, whatsapp, alasset

I am trying to upload a video to `Whatsapp` with an `ALAsset URL,` but it is loading the video when I share it using `UIActivityViewController`

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[assetLibrary assetForURL:self.videoURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    NSArray *objectsToShare =  @[asset.defaultRepresentation.url];
    FrodoInstagramActivity *instagramActivity = [[FrodoInstagramActivity alloc] init];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
        initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:@[instagramActivity]];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
} failureBlock:nil];
```

Comment: Why uploading the URL, upload the asset itself. I think that may solve the issue.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Uploading the asset directly removes all options in acitvityController except my custom activity

Comment: Could you please convert your video asset into NSData and try this ??

Comment: Use this link for reference.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Converting to NSData also does't help.
This code works fine for Facebook, Viber and vimeo but just not whatsapp

Comment: This is how it works, You have to upload the asset as video, for that you have to get the video from the asset. You should do something like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545982/getting-video-from-alasset. I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Another way, try saving this asset to local directory and then try upload.

Comment: Or use document interaction -> http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this noh, "Movie" Your video which saved to local directory from video asset.

```
    NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wam"];

savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];


    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.movie";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = (id)self;

    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
```

Save your asset locally, and get the local URL. Pass that URL path on the above code. Let's see.

Dont create each file locally for each video, just use the same file name for all videos and replace videos. And delete the video from local, after successfully uploaded. [This might help](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013).

Comment: I have already tried but creating a temp copy in case of large files can be an issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: WhatsApp is not loading video with asset url. Every other platform is doing. Still figuring out the actual solution to this problem. For now created a custom activity of whatsapp

Comment: Did you try this _documentInteractionController code ?

Comment: Yes done that. It is working but the only issue is of large files

Comment: As we could see that, we cant directly upload videos to whats app using activityController, we have to use _documentInteractionController. For that we need files which are saved in document directory. Try to save the video to directory using some background process, thats the best way. We dont have any other workaround

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this problem with sharing the link on whatsapp.

In whatsapp sharing was restrit to number of characters.

Please share url and text with maximum 150 characters.

then say what happen.

happy coding :)

Comment: No, the URL is not more than 150 characters. It is assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=004BB7E9-6F9F-4C3A-8FAD-CAC26952708C&ext=mp4